# Where is the default repeat rate for xset stored?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, xset

If I set keyboard repeat rate with say `xset r rate 250 100`, disconnect my usb keyboard and then run `xset -q`, I can see that after disconnecting the keyboard repeat rate is automatically set to the following default values:

```
$ xset -q | grep delay
  auto repeat delay:  660    repeat rate:  25
```

Can I change the default values? Where are they stored? I'm running Debian Sid.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the so-called *seat-defaults* in `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` by adding the relevant parameters (cf. `XSERVER(1)`).

```
-ardelay milliseconds
   sets the autorepeat delay (length of time in milliseconds that a key must be depressed before autorepeat starts).

-arinterval milliseconds
   sets the autorepeat interval (length of time in milliseconds that should elapse between autorepeat-generated keystrokes).
```

(!) For figuring out the `arinterval` in ms from `xset` repeat frequency, compute `1000/freq`.

Mine now says `exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -ardelay 200 -arinterval 20 "$@"`

[found on https://superuser.com/questions/935801/whenever-i-plug-in-another-keyboard-key-repeating-rate-is-reset-to-some-value]

(I used to try to make the repeat rate permanent by setting `Option "AutoRepeat" "190 70"` `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/keyboard.conf`, but that wouldn't stick, so I (helplessly) resorted to running a per-minute `xset` cron job XD)

Answer (score 2):

When we change the settings at a bash prompt, the new settings seem to be stored only in the memory of the running X Server.

To make the changes persistent, you may have luck uncommenting the "KEYBOARD_RATE" and "KEYBOARD_DELAY" lines in `/etc/kbd/config` if your system has that file.

Otherwise (for Ubuntu, anyway), there tend to be various distro-specific approaches, see: https://askubuntu.com/q/140255/231504

Here's why I'm guessing the values set via `xset` only live in-memory in the X Server:

When I run the command under `strace`, like so:

```
strace xset r rate 175 37
```

It seems (based on my limited experience with `strace`) that the settings are written to a socket, and on my machine the socket is:

```
/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

To see what's on the other end of that socket:

```
sudo lsof +d /tmp/.X11-unix
```

... which outputs:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
Xorg    1635 root    3u  unix 0xffff88046ae4bc00      0t0  24945 /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM
```

...which shows that the process listening to the socket is `Xorg` (aka The X Server). Of course, the X Server could then hypothetically persist the values to non-volatile memory somewhere, but based on multiple anecdotes from users, it would seem that's not the case.

Comment: downvoting an answer without a comment is unhelpful. I upvoted the answer so it gets back to 0.

Comment: Upvote because I didn't know about strace

Answer (score 1):

Maybe https://github.com/SFTtech/xautocfg helps you.

It can automatically set the keyboard repeat rate for newly connected devices, and can run as a your user - it gets notified by the X server when a new device was detected.